# How to insert image tag inside a div in rendered html?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, xslt, pdf.js

I am using pdf.js to show pdf text along with image (which i inserted through xslt) but image is not rendered in produced html.There is only text in rendered html.

Rendered output is

```
<div class="textLayer">
<div data-canvas-width="22.717943046104818" data-font-name="font_p0_1" dir="ltr" data-text-length="6" style="font-size: 8.378597354949745px; left: 110.52924529041462px; top: 627.8325441560373px; -webkit-transform: scale(1.195681212952885, 1); -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%; cursor: text;">Click&nbsp;</div>
.
.
.
.
.
</div>
```

My xslt code is

```
<fo:block space-after="1pt">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
                . Click  here
                <fo:external-graphic>
                                <xsl:attribute name="src">
                                    <xsl:text>url('</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$ImagePath"/><xsl:text>')</xsl:text>
                                </xsl:attribute>
                            </fo:external-graphic>
                            to Open Table
            </fo:block>
```

I have tried following code to insert a div in rendered html

```
  function addDiv() {
        var objTo = $(".textLayer");
        var divtest = document.createElement("div");
        divtest.innerHTML = "new div";
        objTo.append(divtest);
        alert('added');
    }
$(function () {
     addDiv();
    });
```

But div is not inserted into dom.

My project requirements are that when user clicks on image some div should display but how to make image clickable when there is no tag against it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
function addDiv() {
        var objTo = $(".textLayer");
        var divtest = document.createElement("div");
        divtest.innerHTML = "new div";
        objTo.get().appendChild(divtest); 
        alert('added');
    }

$(function () {
     addDiv();
    });
```